# AndEngine Font Issue

Tags: android, andengine, fonts, antialiasing

I am learning AndEngine. I am displaying Hello world using this code:

```
public class myactivity extends SimpleBaseGameActivity
{

 private final int CAMERA_WIDTH = 320;
 private final int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 480;

 private Camera  m_Camera;
 private Scene  m_Scene;

 private Font  font;
 private Text  text;

 @Override
 public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions()
 {
  m_Camera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
  EngineOptions en = new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.PORTRAIT_FIXED, new RatioResolutionPolicy(
    CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), m_Camera);

  return en;
 }

 @Override
 protected void onCreateResources()
 {
    //determine the density
 WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
 Display display = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
 DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
 display.getMetrics(displayMetrics);
 int density = (int)(displayMetrics.density);

 //scale desired size 25 by density
     int fontSize = (int) (25 * density);
  font = FontFactory.createFromAsset(this.getFontManager(), this.getTextureManager(), 1024, 1024, this.getAssets(),
    "times.ttf", fontSize, true, android.graphics.Color.BLACK);
  font.load();



//Texture fontTexture = new BitmapTextureAtlas(1024, 1024, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);
//font = new Font(fontTexture, Typeface.create(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.NORMAL), fontSize, true, Color.WHITE);
//mEngine.getTextureManager().loadTexture(fontTexture);
//mEngine.getFontManager().loadFont(font);

 }

 @Override
 protected Scene onCreateScene()
 {
  m_Scene = new Scene();
  m_Scene.setBackground(new Background(Color.WHITE));

  text = new Text(0, 0, font, "Hello Android", this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
  m_Scene.attachChild(text);

  text.setPosition(CAMERA_WIDTH/2 - (text.getWidth()/2), CAMERA_HEIGHT/2 - (text.getHeight()/2));
  return m_Scene;
 }

}
```

It is displaying the font like this:
[image: Hello Android displayed but with pixelated edges]

As you can see that pixels are stretching and font is looking ugly with too much pixelation. How do I display proper font text with no pixelation or add anti-aliasing to the font?

Comment: Is it possible it is to do with the scaling you are applying to the texture generated from the font?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It actually looks like you are already on the right track with your comments.

Try changing your font initialisation to this:

```
//scale desired size 25 by density
int fontSize = (int) (25 * density);
//define texture for font with BILINEAR scaling
final ITexture fontTexture = new BitmapTextureAtlas(this.getTextureManager(), 1024, 1024, TextureOptions.BILINEAR);
font = FontFactory.createFromAsset(this.getFontManager(), fontTexture, this.getAssets(),
     "times.ttf", fontSize, true, android.graphics.Color.BLACK);
font.load();
```

Try it out and let us know the results.

Comment: you save my hours infect i am thinking to switch engine :)

Comment: Glad to have helped. There are many engines out there but if it isn't broke - don't fix it. Stick with something you know and you'll be fine. That's why we are here to help you stay on track.